# Why JavaScript methods in React are undefined?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In this section, when I add the JavaScript method to my file, I get this error.

```jsx
import './ExpenseItem.css';

function ExpenseItem(props) {
  const month = props.date.toLocaleString('en-US', { month: 'long' });
  const day = props.date.toLocaleString('en-US', { day: '2-digit' });
  const year = props.date.getFullYear();

  return (
    <div className='expense-item'>
      <div>
        <div>{month}</div>
        <div>{year}</div>
        <div>{day}</div>
      </div>
      <div className='expense-item__description'>
        <h2>{props.title}</h2>
        <div className='expense-item__price'>${props.amount}</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default ExpenseItem;
```

[image]

Comment: Its not the method which is undefined, `props.date` is undefined.

Comment: First of all: what you call "function" is a "Functional Component". Can you provide the code in which the Functional Component is used? The problem is that your data is undefined.

Comment: Pass in some props to the component. Something like `<ExpenseItem date={new Date()} amount="10" />`.

Comment: hello my friend. You are right. that was my fault

Answer (score 0):

Native JavaScript method are available in React but it appears that you aren't passing `date` as a prop to `ExpenseItem`. You should have something like this in the parent component of `ExpenseItem`:

```
<ExpenseItem date={yourDateVariable}>
```